# Easy way of Checking Whether PySpark DataFrame is nested

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any easy way to check whether a PySpark dataframe is nested? I know that you can print out the schema and visually see determine if the dataframe is nested. Is there a programmatic way of checking this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dtypes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dtypes.html) method which returns all column names and their data types as a list and loop over the list to check if it has nested fields.

```
df = # Input dataframe

dt = df.dtypes

 for t in dt:
     if(t[1].startswith('struct')):
             print('nested')
             break
```